# Understanding Mathematical Induction problems

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, education

I have problem to understand this 3 formulas, I am new in this type of problems.
I have to solve this problems by induction.

\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 1}^{j = n} j^3 &= \left(\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}\right) ^ 2  &\text{where } n \geq 1 \\
\sum_{j = 1}^{j = n} j(j + 1) &= \frac{1}{3}n(n + 1)(n + 2)  & \text{where } n \geq 1 \\
\sum_{j = 1}^{j = n} j(j!) &= (n + 1)! - 1 
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Do you know the general approach for proof by induction?

Comment: first summation superscript should be $j=n$ yes

Comment: Hi @J.W.Tanner For me it is a new material of the class, so I do not have a general base of the material yet.

Comment: The general approach is first show the statement is true for a base case, say $n=1$, and then show that if it is true for $n$ then it is true for $n+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner For the first exercise I know that n * (n + 1) / 2 is the sumaturia of the elements from 1 to N, but in general terms the result of the exercise I have no idea.

Comment: Is the statement true for $n=1$?  What would be the statement for $n+1$?  Would that follow from the statement for $n$?

Comment: So, if for the first condition it is satisfactory, for the other cases it would be true?

Comment: By the way, the third statement could be proved without induction by noting that $j(j!)=(j+1)!-j!$, so it becomes a [telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using induction that doesn't use sigma notation.

The OP can put it in their #Education Reference Folder.

Show that

$$\tag 1 1 + 2 + \dots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Base Case:
True when $n = 1$ since $1 = \frac{1(1+1)}{2}$.

Inductive Step:
Assume that $1 + 2 + \dots + k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.
Then $1 + 2 + \dots + k + (k+1) = (1 + 2 + \dots + k) + (k+1) =\frac{k(k+1)}{2} + (k+1) =$
$\quad (k+1) (\frac{k}{2} + 1) =\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

So by induction, $\text{(1)}$ is always true.

Answer (score 0):

The general procedure for a proof by induction is to first show that the base case satisfies that proposition. Then you assume that your proposition holds for some $n$ and show that from their you can get $n+1$ to work.

I'll work the first the one and let you try the others using the same procedure.

We need to show that when $n=1$ the statement is true. clearly $1^3 = (\frac{1*2}{2})^2$. 
Now we assume that the statement is true for some $n$. Then we compute:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}j^3 = \sum_{j=1}^{n}j^3 + (n+1)^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 + (n+1)^3 $$
$$ = \frac{n^2(n^2+2n+1)}{4} + (n^3+3n^2+3n+1)$$
$$ = \frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4} + \frac{4(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)}{4}$$
$$ = \frac{n^4+6n^3+13n^2 + 12n+4}{4} = \left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right)^2$$

Therefore the proposition holds for $n+1$ as well and so must hold for all $n$.

Conceptually think about it as a bunch of dominoes falling over one at a time. The base case guarantees that the first domino falls over, and the step of showing that you can get $n+1$ from the statement being true for $n$ is saying that any domino that falls will hit the next one.

Comment: Hello, I would like you to send me the complete answer, so I can start using it as a reference.These three exercises are practices.

Comment: no problem, I added in the details

Comment: I fix the first ecuation ,is j = 1 to j = n

Comment: @Justing Stevension Apologies, I had to fix the first formula. It was from j = 1 to j = n

Comment: no worries, I assumed that's what it was suppose to be.

Comment: For the third equation, how did you come to the conclusion that is related to telescoping sum?

Comment: No at all jeje, sory. Im new in this topic.

Comment: Write out the first 5 or 6 terms of the series using the form that J.W. Tanner commented and look for cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(n)$ and $G(n)$ be algebraic formulas with a free variable $n.$ (That is,  neither of them specifies what $n$ is, except we will assume that $n$ must be a number.)

For any $n$ let $S_n$ be the  $sentence $ $ F(n)=G(n).$

Suppose the task is to prove that $S_n$ is true for each $n\in \Bbb N. $

For a start, look at $S_1,$ which is $F(1)=G(1).$ This is called the base case. Of course if $F(1)\ne G(1)$ then the task is impossible. If $F(1)=G(1)$ we proceed to what is called the inductive step/part/phase.

We attempt to prove that $S_n\implies S_{n+1}$ for each  $n\in \Bbb N.$ This step does not assume that $S_n$ is actually true for any $n.$

( An amusing example: If $F(n)$ is $n$ and $G(n)$ is $n+1$ then $S_n$ is $n=n+1$ and $S_{n+1}$ is $n+1=n+2,$ and we can prove in this example that $S_n\implies S_{n+1}$ even though $S_n$ is never true.)

A very important technique here is to examine how $F(n)$ is related to $F(n+1)$ and how $G(n)$ is related to $G(n+1).$ For example what is $F(n+1)-F(n)$? In some Q's we examine  $F(n+1)/F(n)$.

With regards to $F(n+1)-F(n)$: If $S_n$ is true  then $F(n)=G(n),$ which implies the following  sentence:  $$S_{n+1}\iff F(n+1)=G(n+1) \iff$$ $$\iff F(n+1)-F(n)=G(n+1)-F(n)\iff $$ $$\iff F(n+1)-F(n)=G(n+1)-G(n).$$  In many Q's the formulas $F(n+1)-F(n)$ and $G(n+1)-G(n)$ are much simpler than the formulas $F(n)$ and $G(n).$ And it might not be hard to prove (without any assumptions about the truth of any $S_n$) that $F(n+1)-F(n)=G(n+1)-G(n)$ for each  $n\in \Bbb N.$ If we can, then we do have $S_n\implies S_{n+1}$ for each $n\in \Bbb N.$

Finally we place all this next to the Principle of Induction: If $S_1$ is true and if $S_n\implies S_{n+1}$ for each $n\in \Bbb N,$ then $S_n$ is true for each $n\in \Bbb N.$

Example: $F(n)=\sum_{j=1}^nj^3$ and $G(n)=(n(n+1)/2)^2.$ We check that $F(1)=1=G(1).$ Now for any $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $$F(n+1)=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}j^3=(n+1)^3+\sum_{j=1}^nk^3=$$ $$=(n+1)^3+F(n)$$ so $F(n+1)-F(n)=(n+1)^3....$  And $(n+1)^3$ looks simpler than the formula  $F(n).$

Now use the definition of $G(n)$ to  prove that $G(n+1)-G(n)=(n+1)^3 $ for any $n\in \Bbb N,$ and you're done.

Remark: It has been said that $\sum_{j=1}^nj^3=(n(n+1)/2)^2$ "looks like a  mistake", as if someone accidentally wrote the square of the formula for $\sum_{j=1}^nj$ on the RHS (Right Hand Side). But it's correct. E.g. $1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3=100=(1+2+3+4)^2.$